# Many Vectorization with a smaller chunk of data vs Less Vectorization with a larger chunk of data

Tags: c, loops, vector, vectorization, nested-loops

I am optimizing an application and I have been stuck in a loop. I just want to vectorize a loop which is a nested loop. What exactly this loop does is just multiplying two arrays' values and add up. Then, find out the minimum value within the results. The original code is like the below.

```
float min = 0xffffffff;

for(i=0; i<limit_x; i++){
    for(j=0; j<limit_y; j++){
        for(k=0; k<limit_z; k++){
            temp += x[i][k] * y[j][k];
        }
        if(min > temp){
            min = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

As a matter of course, the vectorization occurs at inner-most loop, and it is guaranteed that x and y are aligned by the vectorization register width. In this code, I think vectorization is not contiguous because of comparing and setting up the minimum value. So I modified this code like the below.

```
float min = 0xffffffff;

for(i=0; i<limit_x; i++){
    for(j=0; j<limit_y; j++){
        for(k=0; k<limit_z; k++){
            temps[i] += x[i][k] * y[i][k];
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; i<limit_x; i++){
    if(min > temps[i]){
        min = temps[i];
    }
}
```

I expected for this to improve the performance because it will keep doing vectoized multiplications for the whole data without getting disturbed by comparing and getting minima. But the execution timing is different with my expectation. The previous one is slightly better than the new code.

Is there anyone who can explain why?

Comment: What compiler/development environment are you using? Are you specifying any vectorization directives to the compiler? Have you disassembled the relevant function to determine if the compiler is making an attempt to vectorize the inner loop?

Comment: I am using icc and the cpu is xeon E5 series. I just allocated all the arrays, x,y and z aligned by the vectorization bandwidth and compiler's reporst said it is totally aligned and vectorized well. When I disassemble the code, the second code is even shorter! I don't have any idea why it takes more time.

Comment: When you disassemble the compiler, do you see vector instructions? If those aren't present, then no vectorized acceleration is taking place.

Comment: Yes I saw the vector instructions and it is showing better performance than without vectorization. I am pretty sure vectorization is working well.